# Ошибка в ООП Python

Tags: python, ооп

Есть некий класс и внутри него есть функция (get_html) и при попытке обратиться к какой либо переменной(HEADERS) выдает ошибку что нету такого класса.

```
class main_pars:
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0',
        "accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8" 
    }

    def get_html(url: str, params=' '):
        return requests.get(url, headers = main_pars.HEADERS, params=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

А так:

```
class main_pars:
    HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0',
    "accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8" 
    }

    def get_html(self, url: str, params=' '):
        return requests.get(url, headers = self.HEADERS, params=params)
```

В большинстве ЯП использование члена с именем класса означает, что этот член статический, но член HEADERS не объявлен как статический.

Для проверки работы из get_html просто возвращаю HEADERS:

```
class main_pars:
    HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0',
    "accept": "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8" 
    }
    def get_html(self):
        return self.HEADERS
a = main_pars()
print( a.get_html())
```

Результат:

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0', 'accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8'}

Comment: В этом случае не видит HEADERS и выдает ошибку NameError: name 'HEADERS' is not defined

Comment: @patifon сейчас проверь, в Питоне нужно использовать явный указатель на объект

Comment: Это не функция, а метод класса, так он не будет работать. Чтобы он работал нужно поставить декоратор - что бы заработал так:   main_pars.HEADERS

Comment: Работает, см. ответ